# Terraform - List of destructive parameters

Tags: terraform

some existing resources will be re-created if parameters are changed, one example is `ebs_block_device` which will even re-create the EC2 instance on AWS if you change e.g. the `volume_size` parameter.
is there a list of such Terraform resources/parameters so we use them carefully?

Comment: This is not Terraform-specific, rather provider specific. You should probably go through the AWS API spec to know that. Or CloudFormation.

Comment: For example, take a look at the note (in red): https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#cfn-ec2-instance-blockdevicemappings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Terraform's model, the decision about whether a particular change can be made using an in-place update or whether it requires replacing the whole object is made dynamically by the provider during the planning step.

Unfortunately, that means that there isn't any way to systematically enumerate all of the kinds of changes that might cause each of those results: those rules are represented as executable code inside the provider plugin, rather than as declarative metadata in the static provider schema (which you can see with the `terraform providers schema` command).

Although it's true that in many cases *any* change to a particular argument will require replacement, Terraform is designed to allow providers to implement more specific rules if necessary, such as when a remote system allows upgrading a database engine to a newer version in-place but requires replacement to *downgrade* the same database engine. A provider implements that during the planning step for that resource type, by comparing the previous value with the new value to determine whether the new value is "older" than the previous value, following whatever rules the remote system requires.

Because of that, the only *totally-reliable* way to determine whether a particular change will require replacement is to try making the change and run `terraform plan` to see how the provider proposes to implement the change.

Sometimes provider developers include details in their own documentation about which changes will require replacement, but in other cases they will assume that you're familiar with the behavior of the underlying API and rely on that API's own documentation to learn about what can be changed with an in-place update.